# How to know if a as.POSIXct date time is AM/PM in r?

Tags: r

I have a column with date and time in the as.POSIXct format e.g. "2019-02-23 12:45". I want to identify if the time is AM or PM and add AM or PM to the date and time?

the following code creates an example dataset for representation:

```
ID <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4))
    DATE <- data.frame(as.POSIXct(c("2019-02-25 07:30", "2019-03-25 14:30", "2019-03-25 12:00", "2019-03-25 00:00"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
DATEAMPM <- data.frame(c("2019-02-25 07:30 AM", "2019-03-25 14:30 PM", "2019-03-25 12:00 PM", "2019-03-25 00:00 AM"))
AMPMFLAG <- data.frame(c(0,1,1,0))

test <- cbind(ID,DATE,DATEAMPM,AMPMFLAG)
names(test) <- c("PID","DATE","DATEAMPM","AMPMFLAG")
```

Would like to create the DATEAMPM and AMPMFLAG columns as represented in the code above.

I have seen character strings of the form "2019-09-23 08:45 PM" converted to 2019-09-23 20:45" by specifying the argument as below, but do not the other way around to incorporate AM/PM into the date time

```
as.POSIXct(strptime(,format="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p"))
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `format` to get the data with `AM/PM`

```
test$DATEAMPM <- format(test$DATE, "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
test$AMPMFLAG <- +(grepl("PM", test$DATEAMPM))
test

#  PID                DATE            DATEAMPM AMPMFLAG
#1   1 2019-02-25 07:30:00 2019-02-25 07:30 AM        0
#2   2 2019-03-25 14:30:00 2019-03-25 02:30 PM        1
#3   3 2019-03-25 12:00:00 2019-03-25 12:00 PM        1
#4   4 2019-03-25 00:00:00 2019-03-25 12:00 AM        0
```

Also note that when you convert `14:30:00` in `AM/PM` it would be `02:30 PM` and not `14:30 PM`.

Comment: thanks Ronak, another question: what does + indicate in "+(grepl ("PM", test$DATEAMPM))" ? I used ifelse(grepl("PM",test$DATEAMPM),1,0) and it worked. Curious on what "+" means

Comment: It's a trick for converting a `logical` into the equivalent `integer`. C.f., `+TRUE` and `+FALSE`. You can equivalently do `as.integer(grepl(...))`, though ... code-golf.